# Rails 4 Alternate Background for Row Item

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been following along with the "Agile Web Development with Rails 3.2" book, however I'm using rails 4.2.1 and it hasn't been an issue up until I've tried to alternate the background color of rows. Part of chapter six in the book.

In my products.css.scss file I have:

```
.list_line_even {
  background: #e0f8f8;
}
.list_line_odd {
  background: #f8b0f8;
}
```

In my index.html.erb I have:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Listing Products</h1>
<table>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr class= "<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') -%>">

  <td>
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>
  </td>

  <td class= "list_description">
    <dl>
      <dt><%= product.title %></dt>
      <dd><%= truncate(strip_tags(product.description), length: 80) %></dd>
    </dl>
  </td>

  <td class= "list_actions">
    <%= link_to "Show", product %><br/>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %><br/>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete %>
  </td>

</tr>

  <% end %>
</table>

<br/>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

My page source shows each of the items as alternating between:

```
<tr class= "list_line_odd">
<tr class= "list_line_even">
```

and so on...

Everything seems to work except the background color. I tried changing the css.scss file to have just "red", and "blue" for the colors. It didn't change anything.

Much thanks!

Comment: Try removing the whitespace between `class=` and `"`

Comment: Didn't change anything :/

Comment: Try to check if `products.css.scss` is loaded

Comment: @ManojKumar thats not going to help at all

Comment: try moving that style for line_line_even and list_line_odd from products.css.scss to application.css.scss. See if it works. If it works then it means your product.css.scss is not loaded.

Comment: products.css.scss isn't loaded. Moving the item to application.css.scss made the lines alternate colors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if `products.css.scss` is loaded. You can put your styles to the `application.css.scss` to check if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, picking up Rails 4.2 in 2019 :P However, I ran into this issue and wanted to share what I found in the rare event someone else runs into this.

I had this same problem. However, it wasn't from the CSS not loading. Rather, there was no container with the .products class such that it would apply. I dynamically added the class to the body tag via Firefox and it started working.

If you look at the snippet of code provided for the /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, this file sets the body class accordingly. However, the book presents this as the default file rather than telling you to make any changes - which appears to be in error.